# Zend_config.h on windows

Tags: php, windows, swig

I'm trying to build PHP extension on Windows using SWIG. Resulted .c file require zend_config.h to build. 
So I've downloaded `php-devel-pack-7.4.6-nts-Win32-vc15-x64` and tried to configure it to get the header

```
C:\Users\Vadim\php-devel>phpize
Rebuilding configure.js
C:\Users\Vadim\php-devel
Now run 'configure --help'

C:\Users\Vadim\php-devel>configure
Must be run from the root of the extension source
```

I've built PHP from sources and there still no zend_config.h. But on linux it appears right after configure. How can I get in on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

This means that the `configure` script cannot detect file `config.w32`, this is how it figures out that you are correctly at the root of the extension. Under Mac/Linux, the file used for that purpose is `config.m4`.

If it is your code, you should create that `config.w32` file, otherwise it may be that no effort has been made to port that extension under Windows.